# Looking for a better way to avoid flickering (wxpython on windows)

Tags: python, wxpython

I did find `SetDoubleBuffered(True)` in parent panel would fix the flickering problem(mainly from `wx.StaticText`), but it slows down the whole UI especially the `ObjectListView` element when you sort a column. So I searched a bit and according to https://wiki.wxwidgets.org/Flicker-Free_Drawing, get rid of background erasing for `wx.StaticText` should do the job:

```
class NoFlickeringTxtCtrl(wx.StaticText):
    def __init__(self, parent, id=-1, label="", pos=wx.DefaultPosition,
                 size=wx.DefaultSize, style=0, name="staticText"):
        wx.StaticText.__init__(self, parent, id, label, pos, size,
                            style, name)

        self.Bind(wx.EVT_ERASE_BACKGROUND, self.OnErase)

    def OnErase(self, evt):
        evt.Skip()
```

But sadly it does not work, so I was wondering is there a better way to avoid flickering for `wx.StaticText`?

Answer (score 0):

As far as I can tell, your code does **not** get rid of background erasing. For that to happen, you would have to replace `evt.Skip()` by `pass`.

If that also does not work, try to discard the `EVT_ERASE_BACKGROUND` for the parent panel of the `StaticText` (this helped me to get rid of flickering when painting a panel on `EVT_PAINT`).

Comment: Sorry to hear that. For the sake of documentation can you post a minimal running example?